# modify the_post_navigation to include taxonomy terms in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation, taxonomy

I have modified the_post_navigation $args to navigate within specific taxonomy terms by changing 'in_same_term' parameter to TRUE. It works just fine. What I would like to do is add the taxonomy term name to the 'prev_text' and 'next_text' parameters so that instead of the links just displaying "Next: (Post Title)" is displays "Next (Taxonomy Term): (Post Title)". I think you would need to get the term from the page, store it in variable like I am already doing to display the term name at the top of the page :

```
<?php global $post;

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'resource_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
echo $term->name;
} ?>
```

But then how do I get that variable in the 'prev_text' and 'next_text' parameters? This is my current code:

```
$args = array(
            'prev_text'          => '&#8592;Previous<span>%title</span>',
            'next_text'          => 'Next<span>%title</span> &#8594;',
            'in_same_term'       => true,
            'taxonomy'           => 'resource_cat',
            'excluded_terms'     => 1,
            'screen_reader_text' => 'Post navigation'
        );
        the_post_navigation($args);
```

Or is this the entirely wrong way to go about this?

A desired end result example of a Next link using the below criteria would be:

```
CPT=resources (using single-resources.php template)
Taxonomy=resource_cat
Taxonomy Term=Podcasts
```

Desired result: Next Podcast: "Name of Podcast"

If anyone could help me with the correct syntax or point me in a better direction it would be greatly appreciated!! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work if there is only one `resource_cat` term assigned to the post:

```
$args = array(
  'prev_text'          => '&#8592; Previous ' . $term->name . ': <span>%title</span>',
  'next_text'          => 'Next ' . $term->name . ': <span>%title</span> &#8594;',
  'in_same_term'       => true,
  'taxonomy'           => 'resource_cat',
  'excluded_terms'     => 1,
  'screen_reader_text' => 'Post navigation'
);
the_post_navigation($args);
```

I tested this code on my own install and it works for me.

FYI: If there is more than one term assigned to the post the navigation link will only show the name of the last term in your loop at the top of the page.

Comment: Thats what I needed, Had given that a try but must have had the syntax wrong. thanks so much for your help. Would you happen to know if there is a way to eliminate the automatic colon?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "automatic", but the colons in the Next/Previous labels are right there in the `$args` array after `$term->name` variable. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike. The I used your code it displayed 2 colons. So I deleted the one in the modified code. Its not super important but it would be useful for styling if I could eliminate the one that appears to be automatically generating.